# How do I move a GameObject using .AddForce in the direction of a rotation of another GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

For context, I am using Unity to develop a VR Game. In this game, the rotation of your hands can alter the direction of flight (Similar to "Richie's plank simulator"). I am trying to apply a force to the character rigidbody that is opposite to the orientation of the hands. How would I go about doing this?

I tried to do this by writing my own function to convert from `transform.localRotation` of each hand into a normalized Vector3 (that I can apply on the main rigidbody using rb.AddForce()) that represents the amount of force in each direction (-1 = backwards along the axis, 0 = nothing, 1 = forwards along the axis). I cant work out how to do this simply. I would assume unity has a built in method but i cant find anything along the lines of what im trying to do right now.

EDIT: Is it transform.eulerAngles?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by opposite direction? Maybe then we can help you:) The general approach would be to use world rotation of your hands and apply whatever you mean by opposite within the AddForce.

Comment: Im trying to do iron man hand thruster style flight. But apply all the forces to the player rigidbody, rather than the hands. However, the direction of flight will be controlled by the combined orientation of the hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your clarification in the comments, I can suggest you the following approach:

1. Get the vector pointing out of your hands (more specifically palms from what I got from your comment) in world (player) coordinates since `AddForce()` applies in world coords.

For that, either you can determine it directly in world coords or get the vector in local coords and transform it into world coords. Maybe you can use the `Transform.forward`, `.up` or `.right` vector if one of them is pointing in that direction locally. To convert from local to world coords, use `playerTransform.TransformDirection(localVector3dPointingOutOfPalm)`. This assumes that the player is not parented in any way and actually in world coordinates meaning on the highest level in scene hierarchy. (Please someone correct me here if I'm mistaken).

2. Do this for the left and right hand/palm.
3. If you have used the `Transform.forward`, `.up` or `.right` vector, you already have normalized vectors at hand. If this was not the case, normalize the resulting world vectors using `Vector3.Normalize()` or `Vector3.normalized`.
4. Now you have world/player vectors pointing out of each palm which are of magnitude one. Before applying a force, you can adjust the intensity by scaling (multiplying) the vectors by some factor.
5. What's left to do is to actually `AddForce` to the player:)

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up simplifying to this:

```playerRigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward.x * boostMultiplier, transform.forward.y * boostMultiplier * 4, transform.forward.z * boostMultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);```

Comment: Great to hear that it helped! Good luck with your project!